# Why does my Date return false with regular expression?

Tags: php, regex, datetime, date, preg-match

This is the regular expression I am using:

```
if (preg_match("/^[0-9]{1,2}\/[0-9]{1,2}\/[0-9]{4}$/", $_POST["collection-date"]) === 0) {
        $errors .= "\n Error: Invalid Collection Date";
        $collectiondate = FALSE;
    }
```

Currently `$_POST['collection-date']` equals `15/02/2012` and it still returns false. Why is this?

Thank you for any suggestions.

Comment: Please add the output of `var_dump($_POST['collection-date']);` to your question.

Comment: Is there any whitespace before or after the string in `$_POST['collection-date']`?

Comment: I get this: string(0) ""

Comment: @mcgarriers: That would be why the regex is returning false :-P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$split = explode('/', $date);
if (!isset($split[2]) || !checkdate($split[1],$split[0],$split[2])) {
    $errors .= "\n Error: Invalid Collection Date";
    $collectiondate = FALSE;
}
```

This also validates false if someone enters an invalid date, such as `99/99/2012` or `31/02/2012`, which you probably want as well.

Comment: You could also add `|| isset($split[3])` to that `if` statement as well in case someone enters `15/02/2012/someotherstuffhere` if necessary, or just use the variables from `$split` and forget about anything after if they add another slash and more content.

Comment: Many, many thanks Mike. Your solution did the trick. Now to read Glitch's comments :-)

Answer (score 1):

I've checked this regular expression and it works.

I have small advice to you, don't check number of matches in `preg_match()` (I've commonly seen this). It's very confusing, trust me. `== 0` means if it wasn't found. Personally, I just use it in boolean content, even if `preg_match()` returns integer (number of matches) and not boolean. But it's not really important - `0` in PHP is `false` and other integers are `true` in boolean context. It usually matches with your expectations in this case - 0 matches usually means fail.

Second, there is no assignment to `$collectiondate` other than `false`. I don't know if it is intentional, but if you never send any positive value, it's usually `null` or `false`. In boolean context, both of those values return `false`. In fact, `false == null` because of `null` being converted to boolean (but `false !== null`, because `!==` skips any conversions (it's good idea to use `===` instead of `==` for reasons mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/a/80649/736054)).